# Is it possible to do SQL injection (HIGH Level) on Damn Vulnerable Web App?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, dvwa

I searched all over google to see how it would be possible to bypass the following (it's from the high level of security from [DVWA](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/)):

```
<?php    

if (isset($_GET['Submit'])) {

// Retrieve data

$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = stripslashes($id);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);

if (is_numeric($id)){

    $getid = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($getid) or die('<pre>' . mysql_error() . '</pre>' );

    $num = mysql_numrows($result);

    $i=0;

    while ($i < $num) {

        $first = mysql_result($result,$i,"first_name");
        $last = mysql_result($result,$i,"last_name");

        echo '<pre>';
        echo 'ID: ' . $id . '<br>First name: ' . $first . '<br>Surname: ' . $last;
        echo '</pre>';

        $i++;
    }
  }
 }
?>
```

Is it possible to crack that?

Also, my other concern is on Medium level. It does have the mysql_real_escape_string() working, but when you use the same SQL injection from Low level AND you remove the quotes, it bypasses the protection. Why is that? How come it was so easy to bypass mysql_real_escape string?

The code (concise version) of the Medium level is this:

```
   $id = $_GET['id']; 
   $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id); 
   $getid = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = $id";
```

Comment: You can look this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5nrCCL4LIc
This video explain how you can succeed the sqli high with sqlmap.

Comment: All they are doing is using the cached session files from their medium and low exploits. It doesn't work if `--flush-session` is specified.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The ‘high’ example is not exploitable. It's not a *good* approach (in modern code you would use parameterisation instead of calling `mysql_real_escape_string`, and `stripslashes` is a relic of an era of magical quotes that is thankfully over), but it is designed not to be immediately vulnerable.

(To SQL injection anyway. It *is* vulnerable to HTML-injection leading to XSS issues, thanks to those horrible `echo`s, but that's another story.)

> How come it was so easy to bypass mysql_real_escape string? [in the Medium example]

Because `mysql_real_escape_string` is designed to escape characters for safety when included in an SQL string literal context. Without any surrounding single quotes in the query's injection point, you're not in a string literal context, you're in a raw SQL context.

Comment: The last part is very interesting. Could you expand on that string literal vs raw SQL context and how it changes things?

Comment: @markus-tharkun because if you pass `3 OR 1=1` through `mysql_real_escape string` you still get `3 OR 1=1`. If the query is built like `$query = "$sql = select * from users where id = $id"`, then feeding `3 OR 1=1` will return all rows. whereas `$query = "$sql = select * from users where id = '$id'"` (note the quotes around `$id`) would prevent this type of injection.

Answer (score 11):

SQL Injection is **not possible** in this situation.  This code is preventing SQLi properly and even if the platform is old or misconfigured,  it should still be immune to SQLi.

...  In a slightly different configuration it maybe vulnerable.

If `is_numeric()` was removed, `mysql_real_escape_string()` was replaced with `addslashes()`, and the server was configured to used the GBK language set,  then there is the [possibility of a multi-byte attack using the GBK language encoding](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string).

Answer (score 9):

Here's something interesting: **The high level in DVWA is not meant to be exploitable**. It's the "correct" and safe implementation of the concepts as the DVWA's author saw fit at the time.
So, it's very natural that you're unable to perform SQL Injection at the high level. If you actually do, you would be discovering something new. A zero-day, maybe.

I've been playing with DVWA for years and I had to learn this the hard way.

Comment: It's still a silly implementation. Three different "sanitization" functions instead of converting to the appropriate type. Presumably it's an integer, so why not simply `$id = intval($_GET['id'])`?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Hey, I agree with you. I wouldn't have done it that way either, but I've tried my best to make it clear in my answer that this is (apparently) what the DVWA's authors saw fit at the time. You're welcome to ask him/them.

Comment: You have to be careful with intval and how it treats non numeric values. From the PHP documentation on intval:  "Strings will most likely return 0 although this depends on the leftmost characters of the string". I don't see it causing an issue in this case, but it could though.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to DVWA 1.9, DVWA was using 'high' as the highest security level while currently, they use 'impossible' security level. So in 'high', it is possible to do any other SQL injection for example input like:  ' union select user, password from users; -- . Note that you should have space after -- else the command would be syntactically wrong.

Answer (score -2):

The current code on dvwa for high level sql injection is vulnerable with the same approach.

if you just omit the `Limit` command from the sql query which you can do so by doing ex: `a' or 1=1;#`.

`#` mentioned over here will restrict the `Limit` command mentioned in the last of the query and bingo you get all the users and passwords.

Comment: I'm wondering if you've tested this with the current version of DVWA as the other answers all say that it is not exploitable.

Comment: That is also claimed on [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/55946/10885) to another question.

Comment: I've just tested it ... `a' or 1=1;#` didn't work on DVWA v1.8 SQLi high & medium. It only works for low level