# Why isn't it possible to do SQL injection (HIGH Level) in this example in Damn Vulnerable Web App?

Tags: sql-injection, dvwa

```
$query = " $sql = select * from users where id = '$id' "
```

Won't `$id=3' OR '1'='1` break the query ? 
The doubt arose because someone claimed it can't be broken.

Comment: Have you tried it? It looks injectable to me, but actually trying to exploit it will tell you more reliably.

Comment: Just a note to some reviewers that breaking DVWA doesn't really apply as _"Questions asking us to break the security of a specific system for you are off-topic unless they demonstrate an understanding of the concepts involved and clearly identify a specific problem."_ It's a training app and meant to be broken. Cheers!

Comment: Try out the exploit and see what it kicks back.

Comment: Ya I tried and it actually executed sucessfully.

Answer (score 2):

The high level is meant to be the secure implementation and *should* be unbreakable.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/RandomStorm/DVWA/blob/master/vulnerabilities/sqli/source/high.php) you can see that there is verification that `$id` is a number.

```
if (is_numeric($id)){

        $getid = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = '$id'";
```

Therefore it is not possible for the `id` parameter to be changed to anything that will break the parameter out from the data value context and into the query context.

Comment: Actually **$id=3' OR '1'='1** inputs 3 as the id and breaks the query.

Comment: @wanttomasterpython The code in your version seems different than the GitHub source. This won't work with the code in my answer.